# Angular unable to find my other components

Tags: typescript, angular, systemjs

This is my folder structure:

[image: folder structure]

As you can see I have some components but when I try to include one component into another component's file, gulp says it can't find it no matter what url I put..

I've been looking around like crazy as to why this might be happening but all I found was that you need to have a `tsconfig.json` file at the root of your project which I then included, but it didn't seem to do a whole lot. The file itself contains just `{}` which is the bare minimum you should need since gulp takes care of the compiling using `gulp-typescript` ([gulp-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript)).

I'm using `systemjs` to import different classes/modules into different files, and in my `index.html` I've configured it like this:

```
System.config({
  packages: {
    app: {
      format: 'register',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  }
});
```

Then I boot my Angular 2 app like this (also in `index.html`):

```
System.import('./app/assets/scripts/modules/boot/boot').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

Example component file `core.component.ts`:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'; // Works
import {NavComponent} from './app/assets/scripts/modules/nav/nav.component'; // Unable to find this file says gulp while compiling the typescript into js

@Component({
  selector: 'core-app',
  templateUrl: './app/assets/scripts/modules/core/core.component.html', // Also works
  styleUrls: ['./app/assets/scripts/modules/core/core.component.css'] // Also works
})

export class CoreComponent {

}
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your import should probably be

```
import {NavComponent} from '../nav/nav.component';
```

as ES6 imports work with a file path relative to your file.

Your URLs in your component metadata work differently: they are defined for Angular 2, not the compiler.